# controlled-Z rotation gates in symmetrical fashion

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, pauli-gates, universal-gates, phase-kickback

I was going through the qiskit textbook and in [this chapter](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/phase-kickback.html) I came across a statement under the topic "Kickback with the T-gate" related to the Controlled-Z gate that

> the controlled-Z rotation gates are symmetrical in fashion (two controls instead of a control and a target). There is no clear control or target qubit for all cases.

What does it imply exactly?

[image]

Comment: A releted [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13337/9459).

Comment: CZ(control=i,target=j)=CZ(control=j,target=i)...maybe a bit surprising at first...so you can pick either bit for control/target

Answer (score 1):

For the mathematical explanation, check here: [Why is the action of controlled-Z unaltered by exchanging target control qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13334/why-is-the-action-of-controlled-z-unaltered-by-exchanging-target-control-qubits/13337#13337)

Maybe it would help you to see CZ in a different (symmetric) notation, like its current representation in Qiskit:

```
from qiskit import *
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.cz(0,1)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image: a CZ gate represented as a symmetric gate]

Answer (score 1):

Exchanging the two qubits swaps the basis states $|01\rangle \leftrightarrow |10\rangle$, but keeps $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ unchanged. Suppose you have a gate whose action on the computational basis is

$$
|00\rangle \to a|00\rangle \\
|01\rangle \to b|01\rangle \\
|10\rangle \to c|10\rangle \\
|11\rangle \to d|11\rangle.
$$

If you swap the inputs you obtain the gate whose action on the computational basis is

$$
|00\rangle \to a|00\rangle \\
|01\rangle \to \color{red}{c}|01\rangle \\
|10\rangle \to \color{red}{b}|10\rangle \\
|11\rangle \to d|11\rangle.
$$

Thus, all such gates are unchanged under exchange of qubits if and only if $b=c$.

Controlled-$Z$ is just such a gate with $a=b=c=1$ and $d=-1$. In fact, all controlled rotations around the $Z$ axis such as the controlled-$S$ gate have  $b=c=1$ and are therefore symmetric under qubit exchange and so we do not generally label their inputs as control and target.