# CNOT expressed with CZ and H gates by taking into account HZH =X

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, pauli-gates

From this [link:](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0002039.pdf)

[image]

Where equation 1 is:
[image]

I can probably brute-force this by explicitly calculating this quantum circuit's effective 4x4 matrix and seeing that its equivalent to this teleportation operation - but what does this have to do with X=HZH? Where is x used here? Is X somehow equivalent to a cNOTgate? X, Z and H are all one-qubit gates...so I don't understand what they mean.

Comment: No, the gates are not the same, as you noticed. The claim is that Eq. (3) does the same as Eq. (1) when applied to $|0\rangle$ on the first qubit and an arbitrary state $|\psi\rangle$ on the second (i.e. it swaps the states). Just compute the action of Eq. (3) on $|0\rangle|\psi\rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three equivalent circuits:

[image]

The second equation can be understood from this related [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13337/9459) about the fact that $CZ_{1 \rightarrow 2} = CZ_{2 \rightarrow 1}$, where first index is the control qubit and the second index is the target qubit. The first equation is similar to this related [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12460/9459), but let's prove it explicitly where we will use $HZH = X$:

\begin{equation*}
I \otimes H \; (CZ_{1 \rightarrow 2}) \; I \otimes H=
\\ = I \otimes H \; (|0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes Z) \; I \otimes H =\\
= |0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes H  H + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes HZH =
\\ = |0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes X = CNOT_{1 \rightarrow 2}
\end{equation*}

because $HH = I$ and $HZH = X$.

Comment: Very clear, thanks for your help. Also I saw your profile and will also be looking into your algorithm tutorials - they look very nice.

Comment: @StevenSagona, Happy to help. Thanks :)