# Phase Kickback and Controlled Rotation - Problem in proving symmetry

Tags: phase-kickback

I am reading through the [Phase Kickback](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/phase-kickback.html#2.2-Kickback-with-the-T-gate-) chapter of the IBM online textbook about quantum computation. It is stated that, when applying any controlled Z-rotation, the concept of test and control qubit is lost. To show this phenomenon, the effect of a Controlled-T gate (Z-rotation of $\pi/4$) on the state $|1+ \rangle$ is demonstrated mathematically. The formal control qubit would be $|+\rangle$ while the target qubit would be $|1\rangle$. As I show in the image, the "target" qubit stays unchanged, while the "control" qubit has got rotated (it has now a relative phase).

I then wanted to prove myself that the same result would be delivered when applying the Controlled-T gate on the state $|+1 \rangle$, which physically would mean to swap the two qubits with respect to the former situation. I would then expect the same result as above, but with the two qubits "flipped" on opposite sides of the tensor product. In this case, however, I get a different result (a global phase). I think that I cannot commutate the tensor product, because this would mean physically swapping the two qubits, right? Can somebody explain to me the conceptual mistake that I am doing?

[image: symmetry_of_controlled_t_gates]

Comment: In your penultimate line, why have you put $e^{i\pi/4}$ in the $|01\rangle$ term?

Comment: Also - would you be able to transcribe your notes to mathjax? Lovely handwriting, we just tend to prefer LaTeX to images of math

Comment: @DaftWullie because I thought that, for the controlled-T operation, the only condition needed to be fulfilled is that the "control" qubit should be in the $|1\rangle$ state, but not necessary also for the "target" qubit. The answer of Davit shows it correctly.

Comment: Yes, exactly - if the control is in $|1\rangle$, apply the $T$ gate to the target. That's different from just applying a phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we apply a phase gate, a relative phase is added (this is the definition that I will use in this answer for the phase gate). In the Qiskit's textbook (and in the textbook by M. Nielsen and I. Chuang) $T$ is defined as a phase gate $P(\frac{\pi}{4})$:

$$
P |\psi \rangle = P (\alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle) = \alpha |0\rangle + e^{i\varphi}\beta |1\rangle \\
P(\varphi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0 \\
0&e^{i \phi}
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad 
T = P(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0 \\
0&e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $P$ is the phase gate, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some initial amplitudes, $\varphi$ is the phase defined by the $P$ gate. Note that only $|1\rangle$ in the superposition state has obtained the phase. The same works for the controlled phase gate: only $|11\rangle$ obtains a phase because the control qubit should be $|1\rangle$ and the target qubit also should be $|1\rangle$:

$$CP_{2 \rightarrow 1} |+1 \rangle = CP_{2 \rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|01\rangle + |11\rangle) = \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|01\rangle + e^{i \varphi}|11\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle + e^{i \varphi}|1\rangle) \otimes |1\rangle$$

where $CP$ is the controlled phase gate, $2 \rightarrow 1$ subscript denotes that the $CP$ gate is controlled by the second qubit. More general proof for $CP_{1 \rightarrow 2} = CP_{2 \rightarrow 1}$ can be derived by using matrix representation of the $CP$ gate. This proof is similar to the proof for $CZ_{1 \rightarrow 2} = CZ_{2 \rightarrow 1}$ that can be found in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13337/9459).

$$CP_{1 \rightarrow 2} = |0\rangle \langle 0| 
\otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes P = \\
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&e^{i \varphi} \\
\end{pmatrix} = \\
=I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0| 
 + P \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1| = CP_{2 \rightarrow 1}$$

---

**Side note about why the "symmetry" is not true for controlled $R_z$ gate in contrast to controlled $P$ gate:**

If for the general case instead of $P(\varphi)$ we will use $R_z(\varphi)$ gate then we will have a different result:

$$CRZ_{1 \rightarrow 2} = |0\rangle \langle 0| 
\otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes R_z
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&e^{-i \frac{\varphi}{2}}&0 \\
0&0&0&e^{i \frac{\varphi}{2}} \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
CRZ_{2 \rightarrow 1} = I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0| + R_z \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1| = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&e^{-i \frac{\varphi}{2}}&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&e^{i \frac{\varphi}{2}} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $R_z(\varphi) = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{-i \frac{\varphi}{2}}&0 \\
0&e^{i \frac{\varphi}{2}}
\end{pmatrix}$. So $CRZ_{1 \rightarrow 2} \ne CRZ_{2 \rightarrow 1}$.
This [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13414/9459) also might be relevant where the difference between the controlled versions of $R_z$ and $U1 = P$ is discussed.